# Vscode : how to automatically display git log at pull?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In Vscode, there are (at least) two ways to update a local repository from a remote one : running `git pull` in a terminal or clicking on the turning arrow on the bottom left of the screen.

If I use the button, all is well updated, but I have no feedback of the files that were updated, while in the terminal this list is displayed in the log.

Actually, the log of the button is available in the `Output > Git` tab, which leads me to my question : is there a way to set VSCode such that this tab is automatically open when I click on the update button ?

Comment: create a `runCommands` key binding that opens the log and executes the pull command

Comment: I looked at how to do this, but I only found key bindings from a combination of key on the keyboard. What did you have in mind with the `runCommands` key bindings ? Thanks

Comment: `runCommands` is the command you bind to a key combo and you add a list of commands to execute, you need VSC >1.76

Comment: or use the extension `multi-command`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a little tricky and may be improved, but that does the job :
from the answer proposed in the comments above, I added a key shortcut to the action `Git: Pull` (<kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>), and another short cut with similar keys (<kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>!</kbd>) to `Git: Show Git Output` (putting twice the same shortcut does not cumulate the actions.

Now if I type <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> + <kbd>!</kbd> the modifications from remote are pulled, and the output is shown !